# Scatter chart with multiple xaxis: top and bottom, grouped

Tags: javascript, charts

Looking for chart library that allows multiple x axis, and allows those xaxis to be displayed both at top and bottom, in a way that top xaxis groups multiple bottom xaxis steps into one group. To illustrate this I created simple sketch for what I am searching for:

[image]

Like on image, top xaxis with the name of [B], groups multiple xaxis at the bottom: 5, 10, 30.
Similarly top xasix C, groups two bottom xaxis 40, 80

Anyone knows library that can achieve this effect?

I've checked: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_libraries

but could not find anything like this in examples, closest was chartsjs with multiple xaxis, but only on the bottom, not top. (https://jsfiddle.net/hamalainen/6c0L1yva/3/)